# Exporting ARIMA-regression forecasts

Tags: export

I'll be grateful if you can answer this. I fit a regression-ARIMA model as

```
      'm1<-arima(y1,order=c(0,1,1),xreg=x1)'
```

Standard command for ARIMA with regressors.

Then I use it to predict ahead:

```
       'f1<-predict(m1,newxreg=x2,n.ahead=5)'
```

standard stuff

The problem appears next, where I get this output (focusing on the part that matters):

```
    [126]  0.160095040  0.350650026  0.281973859 -0.161599717  0.305046264

    $se
    Time Series:
    Start = 131 
    End = 135 
    Frequency = 1 
    [1] 0.2268524 0.2283935 0.2299241 0.2314447 0.2329553
```

I'd overlook that it repeats the entire series, which I'm not interested in; my problem is that I can't export the predictions! When I submit

```
     'write.csv(f1,"out.csv")'
```

I get

```
    Error in data.frame(pred = c(0.303546011854172, 0.240057038087077,     0.125706531559436,  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 130, 5
```

As for the forecasts, the vector f1 appears of length 2, with f1[1] being the 130 original observations, and f1[2] being the 5 forecasts! (Instead of f1[1] being the forecast of the 1st period ahead, f1[2] the forecast of the 2nd period, etc)

Any ideas of what's going on and what can I do about it?
And to intrique you even more, the problem only appears when I use regressors! Everything works well if I only have ARIMA!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This Q is difficult to answer without a minimum reproducible example. Nevertheless, because you used the default argument `se.fit=TRUE` in `predict`, `f1` should be a `list` with `length==2`; the first element contains the forecasts and the second element contains the SE's. Both of the list elements should be the same length. The fact that they are not indicates something else is wrong because this should work `write.csv(matrix(unlist(f1),ncol=2),"out.csv")`.

Comment: Thank you this! Setting se.fit=FALSE solved my problem!